# CSS Section Seperater issues on ios,safari vs android

Tags: css, svg, background

I'm using the CSS down arrow separators on the first two sections of my website.

code: http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE

```
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
```

```
#bigTriangleColor path {
fill: #fff;
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 2;
```

}

site: https://wapp.guru/

They look sweet! But on Safari and Safari iOS there is a 1px line at the top of the SVG. So I fix this by adding a -1px margin up top and this works fine on all windows and mac browsers including iOS.

However when I add the margin this breaks the Android phone/tablet version showing a 1px line either on the top or bottom.

I tested on the tutorials actual page and get the same issue with these 1px lines.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like some [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)  should do the trick.

Comment: Check out http://codepen.io/lukeyphills/pen/FjygE and open your Chrome Inspector, view the triangle in Nexus 10 and Ipad viewports and notice the lines. Every tutorial I've seen has this issue if the 1px lines either on the top, bottom, or both.

Comment: umm, I didn't notice any extra lines there... can you take a screenshot?